# Trying to imitate a title page

Tags: titles

I need to get the exact same title page as in the following screenshot:

[Source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242480431_A_SIMPLE_CONFIGURABLE_LaTex_PhD_THESIS_TEMPLATE)

[image]

So far I cannot get the same output:

[image]

My chunk of code:

```
\begin{document}

    \frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering
    %
    \UNIVERSITY{{The University of Melbourne}}    
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Update your department and school here:
    \department{{Department of Mad Science}}
    \school{{Melbourne School of Awesome}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Set up the Title Page
    % Change your thesis title and your information here
    \title  {A SIMPLE \& CONFIGURABLE PhD THESIS TEMPLATE}
    \authors  {\texorpdfstring
        {\href{your web site or email address}{Matthew D. H. Lay: }}
        {Author Name}
    }
    \addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}  % Do not change this here, instead these must be set in the "Thesis.cls" file, please look through it instead
    \date       {\today}
    \subject    {}
    \keywords   {}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
\maketitle
```

MWE to run tests:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\drop}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \drop=0.1\textheight
    \centering
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\LARGE CONUNDRUMS\\ AND \\[0.3\baselineskip] PUZZLES}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    \scshape
    Selected and Expanded Papers from the Organisation Working Conference on \\
    Enigmas \\
    Location, date from--to\par
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    Edited by \\[\baselineskip]
    {\Large FIRST EDITOR \\ SECOND EDITOR \\ THIRD EDITOR\par}
    {\itshape Organisation \\ Address\par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape year} \\
    {\large THE PUBLISHER}\par
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Copy the code for \maketitle from your document class, substitute for all the \@title type firelds with the desired text, then play with the sizes.

Comment: Okay but still I cannot draw the line

Comment: `\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}` or `\hrule` should do it.